# Android SDK Startup

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I downloaded the tarball for the android sdk, and in the README is says to run the "android" program. But I can't find it in the files, and running "android" (without quotes) on the command line (I'm on Ubuntu linux) says the command is not found.

Comment: you don't start the SDK, you start one of the tools provided in the SDK bundle, for example, the Package Manager tool, or the 9-patch image tool, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android` binary can be found in the `tools/` directory of your Android SDK installation.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to download [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). It has a runnable binary (after unzip) and it installs the necessary SDK-s as well.

Comment: I did. Android Studio is what I am working with. It unzips, and there are "add-ons", "platforms", and "tools", folder, with a README in the root folder.

Comment: search for studio.sh

Comment: it's in android-studio/bin/studio.sh